# AJV validation in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajv

I am getting an error if the allRequired keyword is set. If it's not given there is no error. The documentation says this keyword must to be given to object types. When it's not given the validation passes even for wrong input (tested via Postman)

Here is the schema, it's exported from another file:

```js
const ticketSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 1,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 1,
    },
    ticketId: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 6,
      maxLength: 6,
    },
  },
  allRequired: true,         // <---- error occurs here
};

export default ticketSchema;
```

Error message:

```
Error: strict mode: unknown keyword: "allRequired"
```

Validation

```js
const ajv = new Ajv();
const validateTicket = ajv.compile(ticketSchema);
const ticket = {
    'first-name': firstName,
    'last-name': lastName,
    'route-id': routeID,
  };

const valid = validateTicket(ticket);
if (!valid) {
  res.status(422).send(validateTicket.errors);
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `allRequired` property in JSON schema. I looked for it up here in [specification](https://ajv.js.org/json-schema.html). It is not there. So, which documentation do you refer to?

There is no `allRequired` property as far as I know.

But, if you want to make all the properties required, you need to specify a property called `required`. It is an array with required field names as elements. So, in your case, it would be:

```
const ticketSchema = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 1,
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 1,
    },
    ticketId: {
      type: 'string',
      minLength: 6,
      maxLength: 6,
    },
  },
  required: ['firstName', 'lastName', 'ticketId']
};
```

**Update:**

`allRequired` is not part of JSON specification. It is part of `ajv-keywords` module. You need to initialize it as follows:

```
const Ajv = require('ajv');
const ajv = new Ajv();
require('ajv-keywords')(ajv);

const validateTicket = ajv.compile(ticketSchema);
const ticket = {
    'first-name': firstName,
    'last-name': lastName,
    'route-id': routeID,
  };

const valid = validateTicket(ticket);
if (!valid) {
  res.status(422).send(validateTicket.errors);
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I will try it.
Here's the link: https://ajv.js.org/packages/ajv-keywords.html#keywords-for-objects

Comment: @NándorKrizbai, updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Update

There were other mistakes too. The `key` names must be the same as given in the scheme, otherwise the validation won't work.

Example:

```js
const scheme = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    firstName: {
      type: 'string',
    },
    lastName: {
      type: 'string',
    },
  },
};

// correct - key names are the same
data = {
  firstName: 'Alex',
  lastName: 'Smith',
};

// incorrect - key names aren't the same
data = {
  'first-name': 'Alex',
  'last-name': 'Smith',
};
```